# Counting rows with missing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to count the number of rows with data missing in any of multiple specified columns. I am currently counting missing data in each column using the formula

```
=COUNTIFS($F7:$F96, "1", P7:P96, (""))
```

I would like to be able to see how much these individual counts are doubling up. Which rows are missing data in any of the 5 columns of interest? If a row is missing data in multiple columns, I need to count this as a single unit.
Another way to consider this is I am trying to count how many rows have a value in all 5 columns (value is a date).

I have tried adapting the above formula to include conditions of `<>` or `""` for each of the columns, and played around with the `AND` and `OR` logic operators but have not been able to get a working formula.

Comment: ,, in fact what U r trying is not clear,,, better [edit] the post & share some screen shot will help us to first understand then fix it,,, !! And you have wrong command syntax for Non Blank cells,, should be like `=COUNTIFS(F2:F97,"1",P2:P97,"<>"&"")` or `=COUNTIFS(F2:F97,"1",F2:F97,"<>")` ☺

Comment: It would be useful to see some sample data and the expected outcome for it

Comment: Could you provide a sample?  If you want to count blanks you can use COUNTBLANK function.